# Maxwell's divergence of electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

According to Maxwell's equations, if we take a circle close to a positive charge (such that the charge is not inside the circle), the divergence of the circle should be $0$ (because there is no electric charge inside the circle). How does that reconcile with the fact that the magnitude of the vectors that go into the circle is larger than that of the vectors that leave the circle (because the $E$ field is stronger closer to the charge by [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law)). It looks like, by that argument, the divergence should be negative.

Comment: All you need to do is just follow any one field line, it doesn't matter if it diverges from another nearby line, any line entering the boundary also exits the boundary.

Comment: but the line entering is stronger than the one exiting

Comment: The "strength" of fields is measured by the density of field lines, not a change in strength of the individual field line.

Comment: *the divergence of the circle should be 0* A circle does not have a divergence. A vector field has a (possibly vanishing) divergence, at each point. Perhaps you mean the *flux* through a *sphere* close to the charge should be zero.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a diagram of the arrangement.

[image]

In terms of field lines it should be obvious that line entering equal lines leaving.

However in term of flux, yes the field is stronger on the right-hand side of the circle but the entering area $A_{\rm e}$ is smaller than the leaving $A_{\ell}$ and that larger area compensate for the weaker field.